# VBA - Variables with formulas to String

Tags: excel, vba, casting, formulas

I'm trying to create formulas inside variable in VBA code. 
When code comes to create mail section, it gets CRASH.

What's wrong with `numer`?

```
Dim numer As Integer
Dim day As Integer

day = WorksheetFunction.TODAY()
numer = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(day, 1)


With OutMail

    .Subject = "text text" &  CStr(numer) & " text text"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA doesn't allow the use of the TODAY() function. Use the Date function instead. Also, an integer can only hold a value up to 32,767. Use a long instead.

```
Private Sub this()
Dim numer As Integer
Dim day As Long

day = Date
numer = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(day, 1)
```